# SwiftUI Freeze device

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `List` with `NavigationLink` in  `NavigationView` and a `Button` for show a modal.

When I show detail no problem, but if I open modal and show detail not working.
My device (iPhone XS) freeze with CPU 100%.

**Code modal :**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct RoomFormView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : RoomFormViewModel
    @Binding var show : Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("Nom de la pièce")
                TextField("Nom", text: self.$viewModel.name) {
                    HelperView.closeKeyboard()
                }
                Spacer().frame(width: nil, height: 15, alignment: .center)
                Text("Etage")
                TextField("Etage", text: self.$viewModel.floor) {
                    HelperView.closeKeyboard()
                }
                Spacer()
                }.padding(22)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                self.show = false
            }) {
                Text("Annuler")
            }, trailing:                     Button(action: {
                HelperView.closeKeyboard()
                self.viewModel.validate()
                self.show = false
            }, label: {
                Text("Valider")
                })).navigationBarTitle("Ajouter une pièce")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you show us the ListRoomViewModel we could try to reproduce...so we can just guess....

Comment: I think problem is more complexity view. When I open and close sheet all list is refresh.

Comment: and you didnt't show us the code for RoomFormView too...so....your question is not good enough....maybe you should read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in `.navigationBarTitle("Ajouter une pièce")` the app freeze with accent **é** or **è**

When I remove accent no problem. The real solution is use `Text("Ajouter une pièce")`

The final code : `.navigationBarTitle(Text("Ajouter une pièce"))`